# How to put the black bands on the iPhone x

Tags: ios, constraints, iphone-x

These days I'm doing an iOS application with swift. The problem is that I anchored everything with the height and length of the screen, so it comes out different. I would like to have the black bands above and below so, as to return to 16:9. And if possible to color them, but this is not very important.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put the content you want to have a `16:9` ratio into its own view.  Anchor the leading and trailing edges of this view to the superview.  Set view height equal to view width with a multiplier of `16:9`.  Center the view vertically. Set background color of superview to *color the bands*.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-think your design and not attempt to do this.  From the iPhone X design guidelines:

> **Don't mask or call special attention to key display features.**
>
> Don't attempt to hide the device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or
>   indicator for accessing the Home screen by placing black bars at the
>   top and bottom of the screen. Don't use visual adornments like
>   brackets, bezels, shapes, or instructional text to call special
>   attention to these areas, either.

If you do try to do what you want your app is very likely to get rejected from the app store.